# How do I send message into dialog if I know dialog_id using facebook api?

Tags: facebook

https://graph.facebook.com/me/inbox gives me json with list of dialogs and I can take the dialog_id from it. But how I send message in the dialog with this dialog_id?

Answer (score 0):

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/inbox` You cannot send messages using the Graph API. The Graph API only has read access to the inbox.

Comment: Requests dialog is for inviting friends to use the application, not for random communications.